# table-striped not working when used with angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using table-striped style provided by Bootstrap in a table. And I am using angular js to populate the data. It is not showing the table in stripe format. Can someone help me in recognizing the error that I am making?

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>H1</th>
      <th>H2</th>
      <th>H3</th>
      <th>H4</th>
      <th>H5</th>
      <th>H6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="e in data.events">
    <tr>
        <td>{{e.e1}}</td>
        <td>{{e.e2}}</td>
        <td>{{e.e3}}</td>
        <td>{{e.e4}}</td>
        <td>{{e.e5}}</td>
        <td>{{e.e6}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you apply the `ng-repeat` on `tr` rather than `tbody`?

Comment: Have you checked if the bootstrap style is really being imported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you meant to put the ng-repeat on the tr element instead of the body. You're repeating the body instead of rows.

Bootstrap alternates the colours on the rows, and since you are creating a new table body with 1 row each, it's only going to show one color.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issue is the placement of the repeat directive. If you move it to your tr element, it should be fine. As is, it is creating a new tbody element for each item in your events array. Since table-striped alternates the background color of even rows, and each tbody contains only 1 row, you aren't seeing that style applied.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>H1</th>
      <th>H2</th>
      <th>H3</th>
      <th>H4</th>
      <th>H5</th>
      <th>H6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="e in data.events">
        <td>{{e.e1}}</td>
        <td>{{e.e2}}</td>
        <td>{{e.e3}}</td>
        <td>{{e.e4}}</td>
        <td>{{e.e5}}</td>
        <td>{{e.e6}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>H1</th>
      <th>H2</th>
      <th>H3</th>
      <th>H4</th>
      <th>H5</th>
      <th>H6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="e in data.events">
        <td>{{e.e1}}</td>
        <td>{{e.e2}}</td>
        <td>{{e.e3}}</td>
        <td>{{e.e4}}</td>
        <td>{{e.e5}}</td>
        <td>{{e.e6}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This should work fine, but you need to repeat the table rows `<tr`>, not the table body `<tbody>`.